# OBJECT has no attribute called 'goto'. Documentation shows it clearly does

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle as t

screen= t.Screen()
screen.title('welcome to my game')
screen.bgcolor('black')

starting_position = [(-40,0),(-20,0),(-0,0)]
segments=[]

for position in starting_position:
  newsegment=t.Turtle('square')
  newsegment=t.color('white')
  newsegment.goto(position)
  segments.append
```

#Says object has no attribute called 'goto'. Documentation says it should.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `newsegment=t.color('white')` does? Specifically, what do you think will happen to the value of `newsegment` as a result? Separately: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/ and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/. You should start by *reading* and *understanding* the error message. Notice how it says that a *specific kind of* object doesn't have that attribute? Notice how that *isn't* the kind of object the documentation talks about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reassign `newsegment=t.color('white')`, then `newsegment` is not longer a turtle object.

```
for position in starting_position:
  newsegment=t.Turtle('square')
  newsegment.color('white')
  newsegment.goto(position)
```

Comment: I concur.  Removing the line newsegment=t.color('white') from the original script runs without the error.

Comment: I think it should be `newsegment.color`, not `t.color`.

Comment: Fudge, thank you!